# Split huge CSV by columns with Miller

Tags: csv, miller

I need to split huge (>1 Gb) CSV files containing 50K+ columns each on a daily basis.

I've found [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html) as an interesting and performant tool for such a task.

But I'm stuck on Miller's documentation.

**How could I split one CSV to `N` smaller CSV files where `N` is a number of rows in my source file?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with this script

```
mlr --csv put -S 'if (NR % 10000 == 0) {$rule=NR} else {$rule = ""}' \
then fill-down -f rule \
then put -S 'if ($rule=="") {$rule="0"}' \
then put -q 'tee > $rule.".csv", $*' input.csv
```

Make a copy of your CSV in a new folder, and then run this script on it.
It will produce a csv file for every 10000 rows.

Comment: Strange, Miller should have a `split` verb https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/#split but the 6.0.0 release doesn't recognize it

Comment: @Fravadona it is not yet in the stable version, you can download the unstable from here, at the bottom of the page https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/actions/runs/1766863694

Comment: Thanks, tested it and it works; shouldn't you make an update to this answer? Now the problem has become quite trivial

Comment: @Fravadona I will do it, when there will be the stable release. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

the answer from aborruso does add a new column `rule` to the output csv files.
If you want to avoid this, use `emit` with `mapexcept` instead of `tee` in the last step, like this:

```
mlr --csv put -S 'if (NR % 10000 == 0) {$rule=NR} else {$rule = ""}' \
then fill-down -f rule \
then put -S 'if ($rule=="") {$rule="0"}' \
then put -q 'emit > $rule.".csv", mapexcept($*, "rule")' input.csv
```